# EXCEL - Strange behaviour with LAMBDA function

Tags: excel, lambda, excel-formula

I have the below LAMBDA function created as a named range (LIST_VALUES);

`=LAMBDA(range,[ignore_header],LET(filtered,FILTER(range,range<>""),IF(OR(ISOMITTED(ignore_header),NOT(ignore_header)),filtered,INDEX(filtered,SEQUENCE(ROWS(filtered)-1,,2)))))`

The function itself works exactly as intended, however, when I wrap the function with ROWS() I get inconsistent behaviour when the ignore_header flag is set to TRUE;

[image]

The above example highlights the issue, cell F8 should equal "3", the same as D8.

**D8**

`=ROWS(LAMBDA(range,[ignore_header],LET(filtered,FILTER(range,range<>""),IF(OR(ISOMITTED(ignore_header),NOT(ignore_header)),filtered,INDEX(filtered,SEQUENCE(ROWS(filtered)-1,,2)))))($A:$A,TRUE))`

**F8**

`=ROWS(LIST_VALUES($A:$A,TRUE))`

Does anyone know what going on here or how I fix it? I'm currently working around the issue by setting ignore_header to false and deducting 1 from the result, which works fine, but I'd really like to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't really step through the internal process within the lambda, so it's difficult to pinpoint where the error would surface (hence the count of '1' for an internal error). But may I suggest to simplify your formula to:

```
=LAMBDA(range,[ignore_header],DROP(TOCOL(range,3),OR(ISOMITTED(ignore_header),NOT(ignore_header))))
```

I can't detect any inconsistency when wrapped in `ROWS()`, eg.: `=ROWS(LIST_VALUES(A:A,TRUE))` worked as expected for me now.

Comment: Hi, this didn't quite work for my requirements as TOCOL doesn't filter out non-empty cells with a blank value ```=""``` which my data contains, however, it did really help me in simplifying my function without any problems with the calculation being wrapped in rows. Thanks! Final solution: ```=LAMBDA(range,[ignore_header],DROP(FILTER(range,range<>""),ignore_header)))```